# locked from "find my device" cannot open Nokia C 110

Tags: google, password, sim-unlocking, nokia

I have a new phone (Nokia C110), but it's locked from Google's "Find My Device". I locked it because I lost the phone, then I recovered it. I tried my "Find my device" password, but can't seem to unlock it. Once you lock it the password field disappears off the website and there is no way to put a different password in or delete the old. Is there any way to unlock my phone without erasing the data?

P.S. I must have spent 6 hours today searching for an answer. Half were about how to do a factory reset because google locks the phone so tightly you have to go through hell even to do that! It won't let me go to settings, I don't have a pattern lock or camera on the main screen, and the google log in screen doesn't come up when I start so all of those solutions are out. Like one of the other folks who asked the question, I didn't have any password on it originally.

Also put a password on it twice. I believe the first one took because later on it said it could not find the device, but I tried both with no luck.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. If you've lost access to your previous account, then please follow the procedure on [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)